# Dirac trace theorem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dirac-matrices, trace

I am unable to prove exactly one trace identity that appears in the appendix of Peskin and Schroeder's QFT book.  Can someone help me?

The theorem [Appendix A.4 eqn (A.28)] says that the order of $\gamma$ matrices inside of a trace can be reversed:

$$\text{tr}(\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu\gamma^\rho\gamma^\sigma\cdots)=\text{tr}(\cdots\gamma^\sigma\gamma^\rho\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu)$$

Can someone help me with this trivial thing...?

Comment: Please see http://www.phy.uct.ac.za/people/horowitz/Notes/GammaMatrices.pdf (the derivation leading to Eq. 23)

Comment: referring proof 7 of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices
should be good